# Pandas time series index attribute error when using TsTables & PyTables in creating a table class

Tags: time-series, timestamp, algorithmic-trading, pytables, pandas-timeindex

I am trying to create a table structure through tb.IsDescription class, then create a .h5 file and populate it with a Pandas Dataframe with Datetime index, using TsTables package. I have already tested the Dataframe and the date time Indexing and both seem to be fine. I believe the issue is with the TsTable package, as it remains 'Unused import statement'. The error I get is: " AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries' has no attribute 'index' ". The reason I am using the TsTAble is that I have heard it is faster than other modules. Any suggestions how to resolve this issue, or any substitute method?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tables as tb                  
import datetime as dt

path = r'C:\Users\--------\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2'



no = 5000000                       # number of time steps
co = 3                               # number of time series
interval = 1. / (12 * 30 * 24 * 60)    # the time interval as a year fraction   
vol = 0.2                                 # volatility

rn = np.random.standard_normal((no, co))
rn[0] = 0.0                                 # sets the initial random numbers to zero

paths = 100 * np.exp(np.cumsum(-0.5 * vol ** 2 * interval + vol * np.sqrt(interval) * rn, axis=0))
                                           # simulation based on an Euler discretization

paths[0] = 100                              # Sets the initial values of the paths to 100

dr = pd.date_range('2019-1-1', periods=no, freq='1s')
print(dr[-6:])                            # the date range appears fine

df = pd.DataFrame(paths, index=dr, columns=['ts1', 'ts2', 'ts3'])
print(df.info(verbose=True))             # df is pandas Dataframe and appears fine
print(df.head())                       # tested a fraction of the data, it is fine


import tstables as tstab             # I get Unused import statement

class ts_desc(tb.IsDescription):       
    timestamp = tb.Int64Col(pos=0)         # The column for the timestamps
    ts1 = tb.Float64Col(pos=1)                 # The column to store numerical data
    ts2 = tb.Float64Col(pos=2)
    ts3 = tb.Float64Col(pos=3)

h5 = tb.open_file(path + 'tstab.h5', 'w')

ts = h5.create_ts('/', 'ts', ts_desc)
          
ts.append(df)                         # !!!!! the error I get is from this code line !!!!
               # value error raised is: if rows.index.__class__ != pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex:
                 AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries' has no attribute 'index'      `
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have run into a version compatibility issue between `tstables` and  your `pandas` versions (assuming you are running any recent pandas version). Based on the [tstables PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/tstables/), the last release of tstables was in 2015. A check of the [tstables github project page](https://github.com/afiedler/tstables) shows there was an issue with Pandas 0.20.3 and use of datetime. The error message is the same as yours: `module 'pandas.tseries' has no attribute 'index' in tstables` See this: [tstables breaks down with Pandas 20.3](https://github.com/afiedler/tstables/issues/7)

The issue has a link to another build that works with Pandas 0.20.3. Development notes state "Removed 'convert_datetime64' parameter on line 245". Not sure if it will work with more recent versions, but worth a try. See this: [schwed2 tstables build](https://github.com/schwed2/tstables)

If that doesn't solve the problem, I suggest running the simple examples provided or run the setup tests. (Note: I could not find the `bpi_2014_01.csv` file to test the bitcoin/bpi example.)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank u sir @kcw78, besides the removal mentioned in the 'schwed2 tstables build' above, I had to comment out two lines below regarding "ValueError" in lines 239 and 240, and this solved the issue:

   ' def append(self,rows,convert_strings=False):
       ...
       ...
            #if rows.index.__class__ != pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex:
                #raise ValueError('when rows is a DataFrame, the index must be a 
                  DatetimeIndex.')

            # Convert to records
            records = rows.to_records(index=True) #, convert_datetime64=False) '